# Associate Visual Studio Online build definition to deployments

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am playing around with Build definitions in Visual Studio Online and find them pretty cool. I've created one and have successfully publish a test Web Api project to Azure. However, I do not get a deployment record under the Deployments tab in the Azure Portal like I do when I queue a build through the XAML build definition that Azure adds when connecting a web app to VS. Does anyone know how to do the same with VSO Build Definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Deployments tab shows only when you "Set up deployment from source control". For example, you create a web app on Azure, then build and deploy with VSO Build vNext, you won't see the Deployments tab at all.

To check whether you have a successful deployment, you can check build log in VSO, as well as go to "visit the portal" on DASHBOARD to get more information of your web app.